# Fixed UIImageView in all viewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I want to have a fixed Image on all my view controllers. When the view changes the image will stay still and on top of everything (something like the `UINavigationBar`). I want to avoid using `UINavigationBar` because of it's limitations. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible you need to place your View inside your window above your view controllers view, something like this :

```
[self.window insertSubview:self.logoButton
              aboveSubview:self.navigationController.navigationBar];
```

This code place a UIButton over the Navigation bar and while the navigation bar animated, the button don't.

I've put that code in :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

This is not exactly what you want, but you should be able to modify it to your needs.

Comment: I tried doing something like this: `UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hadder.png"];
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
        [myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
    [self.window insertSubview:myImageView
                  aboveSubview:self.window];` But I can see the header only in the first ViewController

Comment: @Sha `aboveSubview:self.window ?` that is why it's not working, `self.window is not a subview of self.window`. You probably have a root view controller in your app. put it above the view of your root view controller (after that view have been added to your window so it can find it)

Comment: `FirstViewController *test = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hadder.png"];
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
        [myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
    [self.window insertSubview:myImageView
                  aboveSubview:test.view];` I tried the above code, FirstViewController is the first ViewController right after Navigation Controller. I can still see the header only in `FirstViewController`

Comment: @Sha I notice that your image view would be covering totally a navigation bar, why not just put the navigation bar on your navigation bar and insert your Image view `above your navigationBar` just like in the example I've post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do this using a custom container controller or container views. The easiest way is to use container views in the storyboard. Start with a single view controller, drag in 2 container views, and size them how you want (with the top one at the top of the view, and sized how you want your image). You will get two view controllers hooked up to these container views -- if you're going to do navigation, you should probably delete the bottom one, drag in a navigation controller, and control-drag from the container to hook it back up (you could hide the navigation bar, if you're planning to use your top controller like a nav bar). Any navigation you do in that bottom controller will be confined to that bottom view, and your top image bar will remain in place.

Comment: That's a nice solution. Unfortunately my app needs to be iOS 5 compatible.

Comment: @Sha, I'm pretty sure custom container controllers were introduced in iOS 5. You can still use them, but you'll have to do it in code.